# Recommended developer machine specs for Sitecore Commerce

Tags: sitecore-commerce

What are the recommended specs for a developer machine running a Sitecore 9 commerce solution?

I am running a virtual machine with 4 virtual processors of 2.4 Ghz with 10 GB RAM. Sitecore XP is installed using the single server topology with Sitecore Commerce engine on top. I often find the Commerce Engine using 50-55% (over two processes) and the Solr service using 20-25% of the CPU leaving little left for the IIS worker process to manage requests to my site. Sitecore and the site are quite slow especially when I browse them, especially in the commerce business tools.

Is this expected? Is there something wrong with my setup or should I simply add more power? Normal Sitecore development (no commerce) seems to work okay on this kind of setup.

Comment: It is expected. Sitecore Commerce runs a lot of tasks in the background, especially indexing tasks which are CPU intensive. If you can, try and get SOLR off to another machine, e.g. a shared instance between developers on your team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Per Sitecore Recommendation:

http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreXC_9.0/Installation-Guide/Sitecore-XC-9.0_Installation_Guide(On-Prem).pdf

- RAM - 16 GB
- HDD - 500 GB

I started Sitecore 9 Upgrade  on my 12 GB Thinkpad but the performance was very slow and utilization level of my CPU was hitting 97%. Then I moved to 16 GB RAM and performance improved after that.

**Why we need High end spec Machine:**

1. Sitecore 9 comes with xConnect which is hosted as another website in IIS and 
   consumes Memory
2. Solr runs as a window service in Sitecore 9 which again takes more space
3. When Sitecore Commerce is installed then 4 websites get deployed in IIS and they run concurrently so it consumes more memory.

Comment: My memory use is pretty stable around 50-60% with 10 GB RAM so it seems weird that I need to add more memory (although I reckon that the official docs states 16 GB)

Comment: Some of these services, like SQL and SOLR, they _run_ fine with somewhat limited memory but perform best with lots of it.

Comment: After upgrading to a developer machine with 16 GB RAM everything seems to run smooth - so I am accepting this as the answer